# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, probability, hypothesis-test

I'm using the R function `ks.test()` to test the Uniform distribution of the R random number generator. I'm using the following code:
`replicate(100000, ks.test(runif(n),y="punif")`.

When `n` is less than or equal to 100 it works, but when `n` is greater than 100 I get the following Warning Message:

```
In ks.test(runif(100000), y = "punif") :
  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.
```

What are those "ties"?

Comment: Have you tried `?ks.test`

Comment: Sounds like `runif()` returned duplicate values. Try looking at `x<-runif(100000);ks.test(x, y = "punif");sum(duplicated(x))` instead to see if that's the case. (Because it's random you might not get the same result each time)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you inspect the body of the function `ks.test` you will see the following line somewhere in the body:

```
if (length(unique(x)) < n) {
    warning("ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test")
    TIES <- TRUE
}
```

This tells you that when the number of unique elements in x is below the number of elements - you will get this warning. In other words if your vector has duplicate entries - you will get the warning.

Most likely what happened is that when n > 100 there are more chances to get a duplicated value in there somewhere compared with using n = 100. Since you are repeating this thousands of times the probability for having two identical values in x goes up.

As an example this code didn't give me any warning:

```
set.seed(1234)
smth <- replicate(100000, ks.test(runif(101),y="punif"))
```

Comment: But, what if my data set contains repeating values?

Comment: Have a similar question. Does this mean the test is not valid, if there are ties?

Comment: @JeremyMcNees Please consider looking for an answer in Stats.StackExchange. [HERE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113032/ks-test-and-ks-boot-exact-p-values-and-ties)  is on example that might help you.